# wxHaskell program starts really slow on Windows XP

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I have write a wxHaskell program and it performs very good on Mac. But after lot of troubles and installed wxHaskell on Windows XP, my program take several minutes to start. Currently, the wx library is shared (DLL). Does anyone know what's the problem?

```
MinGW 20120426

wxWidget: 2.9.4

Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0
```